# One row with multiple columns to two columns per row

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having trouble creating a *SQL select* in Oracle, which does the following.

I have a

```
table (col1, col2 ... col15)
```

with 15 columns per row.

How can I make query as follows:

```
row1: col1, col2
row2: col3, col4
row3: col5, col6

...
rowN: col14, col15
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean my "make rows". Do you want this to be the output of the Query? Does Col1,col2 means all rows of the column?

Comment: Yes i want to be output of the Query. One row of table_1 contain data in 15 columns

Comment: I'm still not sure of what you want... If the original table had, say 2 rows, how many rows should your output have?

Comment: rowN: col14, col15 doesnt make sense since the even num column will be the last one. More like `rowN: col13, col14`

Comment: table_1 got colums: Day1_AM, Day2_PM, Day3_AM, Day4_PM... Day15.
I need to construct Query that return data from table_1 like two columns AM, PM

Comment: But how many rows are in this table_1? just one?

Comment: one row is for one person. in my case yes just one row

Comment: Ok.. this is going to be difficult with a query. The table structure is bad. is PL/SQL ok?

Comment: Some sample data and expected output would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all columns are of the same datatype, you could do a union. It will be tedious.

```
SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM TABLE_1
UNION ALL
SELECT COL3, COL4 FROM TABLE_1
UNION ALL
......
SELECT COL13, COL14 FROM TABLE_1
```

If you tell me your a little more about the problem maybe it can be solved in some way other than a plain query?

For example - if you are using another programing language `perl` or `php`, you can select row wise and output 8 lines per row.

Or, if its pure database, you can consider PL/SQL.